# What's wrong with this cheesy riddle?

Tags: riddle, puzzle-creation

To celebrate the 10 years of Stackoverlow, I made an online [cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese/316605#316605),
where one uses the answer to a question to unveil the encrypted message!

The message gets decrypted by hopping back `<decimalPartOfanswer>` times for every letter.

However, it doesn't seem to get any attention. I feel that the way I present it doesn't highlight the way the message gets decrypted.

Any tips on making it more appealing for the reader?

---

<sub>PS: If this is off-topic, let me know!</sub>

Comment: This is definitely a question for the sandbox on Puzzling Meta.

Comment: Should I delete it then or I can somehow migrate it?

Comment: @PerpetualJ No, questions about [tag:puzzle-creation] are on-topic for the main site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the close votes increase in number. Are you sure that my question is ok for this site?

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is what this has to do with riddles. The thing you posted doesn't seem to be a [tag:riddle] but rather something to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your riddle is brilliant. I just think the reason that it hasn't had much attention is that it, at first glance, seems quite complicated so most people just click off of it. Hope that helped. 
P.S. It is very popular now so maybe cange the bit about 'it is not getting much attention'

Comment: William I guess you are the person who upvoted the cheesy riddle in Meta, thanks! If I change it, it might be a paradox for me to ask this question. Thank you for the tip, next time, I will have it mind!

Comment: @gsamaras No problem.

Comment: William I went ahead and edited my cheesy riddle, providing the hint in text, rather than a link to the text, and also a Live Demo button, at the top, instead of the bottom! Thank you again!